# Scaling a table with merged cells to fit an entire page

Tags: tables, landscape, fit

I would like to scale the following table to fit an entire page in landscape mode.

I tried:

`\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{% }`

`\usepackage{adjustbox}`

My code:

```
 \documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
 %This code was written by Mohcine
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
%\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
    \setcellgapes{5pt}
\usepackage{amsthm,amssymb,amsfonts,mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
\begin{center}
 \begin{table}
  %\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
    \begin{adjustbox}{width=1\textwidth}
\makegapedcells
    \begin{tabular}{ | c | *{5}{>{$\displaystyle}c<{$}|}}
    \hline
    Mohcine    &   \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Développement limité en 0 de fonctions usuelles }    & \text{ Equivalents} & \text{ Développements en série entière usuels} \\ \hline
            Théorème         &   \multicolumn{2}{c|}{$\displaystyle
            f(x)\underset{{x\to a}}{=}\sum_{k=0}^{n}a_k(x-1)^{k}+o((x-a)^{n})$}
                                                &  &   f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} a_n(x)^{n}     \\ 
    \hline
Formulaire        &   \multicolumn{2}{c|}{$\displaystyle
            f(x)\underset{{x\to a}}{=}\sum_{k=0}^{n}a_k(x-1)^{k}+o((x-a)^{n})$}
                                               & &  f(x)=\sum_{n\geq 0} a_k(x-1)^{k}    \\ 
    \hline
Ordre   &   DL_{n}(0)   &   DL_{5}(0)           &  &                                      \\ 
    \hline
        $\dfrac{1}{1-x}$   &  \dfrac{1}{1-x}\underset{{x\to 0}}{=}\sum_{k=0}^{n} {x^k} +o(x^{n})  
                        &  \dfrac{1}{1-x}\underset{{x\to 0}}{=}1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5+o(x^{5}) &  & \rm{R}=1,\ \forall x\in ]-1;1[\quad \dfrac{1}{1-x}=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} {x^n}       \\   
    \hline
            $\dfrac{1}{1+x}$   &  \dfrac{1}{1+x}\underset{{x\to 0}}{=}\sum_{k=0}^{n} (-1)^{k}{x^k} +o(x^{n})  
                        &  \dfrac{1}{1+x}\underset{{x\to 0}}{=} 1-x+x^2-x^3+x^4-x^5+o(x^{5}) &  & \rm{R}=1,\ \forall x\in ]-1;1[\quad \dfrac{1}{1+x}=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} (-1)^{n}{x^n}       \\   
    \hline
                $-\ln(1-x)$   &   -\ln(1-x)\underset{{x\to 0}}{=}\sum_{k=0}^{n} \dfrac{x^{k+1}}{k+1} +o(x^{n})  
                        &  -\ln(1-x)\underset{{x\to 0}}{=} x+{\frac {x^{2}}{2}}+{\frac {x^{3}}{3}}+{\frac {x^{4}}{4}}+{\frac {x^{5}}{5}}+o(x^{5})  &  & \rm{R}=1,\ \forall x\in [-1;1[\quad -\ln(1-x)=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} \dfrac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}      \\   
    \hline
            $\ln(1+x)$   &   \ln(1+x)\underset{{x\to 0}}{=}\sum_{k=0}^{n} (-1)^{k}\dfrac{x^{k+1}}{k+1} +o(x^{n})  
                        &  \ln(1+x)\underset{{x\to 0}}{=} x-{\frac {x^{2}}{2}}+{\frac {x^{3}}{3}}-{\frac {x^{4}}{4}}+{\frac {x^{5}}{5}}+o(x^{5})  &  & 
                                                {\displaystyle\rm{R}=1,\ \forall x\in ]-1;1]\quad \ln(1+x)=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} (-1)^{n}\dfrac{x^{n+1}}{n+1} }     \\   
    \hline
                & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{ On en déduit la somme de la série harmonique alternée  $\displaystyle\quad  \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \dfrac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n}=\ln(2)$ } \\  
        \hline

$\exp(x)$   &   {\displaystyle {\rm {e}}^{x}\underset{{x\to 0}}{=}\sum _{k=0}^{n }{\frac {x^{k}}{k!}}+o(x^{n}) }  
                        &  {\displaystyle {\rm {e}}^{x}\underset{{x\to 0}}{=} 1+{\frac {x}{1!}}+{\frac {x^{2}}{2!}}+{\frac {x^{3}}{3!}}+{\frac {x^{4}}{4!}}+{\frac {x^{5}}{5!}}+o(x^{5})} &  & {\displaystyle \rm{R}=+\infty,\ \forall x\in \mathbb{R}\quad {\rm {e}}^{x}=\sum _{n=0}^{+\infty }{\frac {x^{n}}{n!}}}        \\   
    \hline
        $\operatorname {ch} \,x$   &   {\displaystyle \operatorname {ch} \,x\underset{{x\to 0}}{=}\sum _{k=0}^{n }{\frac {x^{2k}}{(2\,k)!}}+o(x^{2n}) }  
                        &  {\displaystyle \operatorname {ch} \,x\underset{{x\to 0}}{=} 1+{\frac {x^{2}}{2!}}+{\frac {x^{4}}{4!}}+o(x^{5})} &  & {\displaystyle \rm{R}=+\infty,\ \forall x\in \mathbb{R}\quad  ,\,\operatorname{ch} \,x=\sum _{n=0}^{+{\infty }}{\frac {x^{2n}}{(2\,n)!}}}        \\   
    \hline
            $\operatorname {sh} \,x$   &   {\displaystyle \operatorname {sh} \,x\underset{{x\to 0}}{=}\sum _{k=0}^{n }{\frac {x^{2k+1}}{(2\,k+1)!}}+o(x^{2n+1}) }  
                        &  {\displaystyle \operatorname {sh} \,x\underset{{x\to 0}}{=} x+{\frac {x^{3}}{3!}}+{\frac {x^{5}}{5!}}+o(x^{5})} &  & {\displaystyle \rm{R}=+\infty,\ \forall x\in \mathbb{R}\quad  ,\,\operatorname{sh} \,x=\sum _{n=0}^{+{\infty }}{\frac {x^{2n+1}}{(2\,n+1)!}}}        \\   
    \hline
                        $\cos \,x$   &   {\displaystyle \cos \,x\underset{{x\to 0}}{=} \sum _{k=0}^{n }{(-1)^k\frac {x^{2k}}{(2\,k)!}}+o(x^{2n}) }  
                        &  {\displaystyle \cos \,x\underset{{x\to 0}}{=}  1-{\frac {x^{2}}{2!}}+{\frac {x^{4}}{4!}}+o(x^{5})}
                                                & {\displaystyle\begin{aligned}[c] \cos \,x-1 &\underset{{x\to 0}}{\sim} -{\frac {x^{2}}{2!}}\\
1-\cos \,x &\underset{{x\to 0}}{\sim} {\frac {x^{2}}{2!}} \end{aligned}}   &
                                                {\displaystyle \rm{R}=+\infty,\ \forall x\in \mathbb{R}\quad  ,\,\cos \,x=\sum _{n=0}^{+{\infty }}{(-1)^n\frac {x^{2n}}{(2\,n)!}}}        \\   
    \hline
            $\sin \,x$   &   {\displaystyle \sin \,x\underset{{x\to 0}}{=} \sum _{k=0}^{n }{(-1)^k\frac {x^{2k+1}}{(2\,k+1)!}}+o(x^{2n+1}) }  
                        &  {\displaystyle \sin \,x\underset{{x\to 0}}{=}  x-{\frac {x^{3}}{3!}}+{\frac {x^{5}}{5!}}+o(x^{5})} &  & {\displaystyle \rm{R}=+\infty,\ \forall x\in \mathbb{R}\quad  ,\,\sin \,x=\sum _{n=0}^{+{\infty }}{(-1)^n\frac {x^{2n+1}}{(2\,n+1)!}}}        \\   
    \hline
        $\arctan \,x$   &   {\displaystyle \arctan \,x\underset{{x\to 0}}{=} \sum _{k=0}^{n }{(-1)^k\frac {x^{2k+1}}{(2\,k+1)}}+o(x^{2n+1}) }  
                        &  {\displaystyle \arctan  \,x\underset{{x\to 0}}{=}  x-{\frac {x^{3}}{3}}+{\frac {x^{5}}{5}}+o(x^{5})} &  & {\displaystyle \rm{R}=1,\  \forall x\in [-1;1](x\not =\pm i)\quad  ,\,\arctan  \,x=\sum _{n=0}^{+{\infty }}{(-1)^n\frac {x^{2n+1}}{(2\,n+1)}}}        \\   
    \hline
            $\operatorname {arctanh} \,x$   &   {\displaystyle \operatorname {arctanh} \,x\underset{{x\to 0}}{=}\sum _{k=0}^{n }{\frac {x^{2k+1}}{(2\,k+1)}}+o(x^{2n+1}) }  
                        &  {\displaystyle \operatorname {arctanh} \,x\underset{{x\to 0}}{=} x+{\frac {x^{3}}{3}}+{\frac {x^{5}}{5}}+o(x^{5})} &  & {\displaystyle \rm{R}=1,\  \forall x\in ]-1;1[\quad  ,\,\operatorname {arctanh} \,x=\sum _{n=0}^{+{\infty }}{\frac {x^{2n+1}}{(2\,n+1)}}}        \\   
    \hline
                    \end{tabular}
    %}
    \end{adjustbox}
 \end{table}
 \end{center}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: I think, you should really tidy up your code.  I found a lot of useless commands, e.g. a `\centering{}` as last element in the third line ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to use an `adjustbox` environment. Better to use a `\scriptsize` directive and to reduce the value of `\setcellgapes`.

In the code below, I've also cleaned up and streamlined various parts of your code. The largest changes should be apparent in the final column, because of the replacement of `\rm R` with `\mathrm{R}`. I've also provided `\mathopen` prefixes for the instances when `]` is used to denote the left-hand edge of an open or semi-open interval. (By default, the math code of `]` is `mathclose`; this distinction affects the way the `-` symbol is interpreted: it could be a binary or a unary operator.)

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
 %This code was written by Mohcine
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{rotating}
\setcellgapes{4pt}
\usepackage{amsthm,amssymb,amsfonts,mathtools}
\DeclareMathOperator{\arctanh}{arctanh}
\DeclareMathOperator{\ch}{ch}
\DeclareMathOperator{\sh}{sh}
\newcommand{\eqx}{\mathrel{\underset{\scriptscriptstyle x\to0}{=}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{sidewaystable}
\centering
\makegapedcells
\scriptsize
\begin{tabular}{ | c | *{4}{>{$\displaystyle}c<{$}|}}
\hline
Mohcine    
&   \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Développement limité en $0$ de fonctions usuelles }    & 
\text{Equivalents} & 
\text{Développements en série entière usuels} \\ 
\hline
Théorème &   
\multicolumn{2}{c|}{$\displaystyle f(x)\underset{\scriptscriptstyle x\to a}{=} \sum_{k=0}^{n}a_k(x-1)^{k}+o\bigl((x-a)^{n}\bigr)$}
&  &   
f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} a_n(x)^{n} \\ 
\hline
Formulaire        &   
\multicolumn{2}{c|}{$\displaystyle f(x)\underset{\scriptscriptstyle x\to a}{=}\sum_{k=0}^{n}a_k(x-1)^{k}+o\bigl((x-a)^{n}\bigr)$}
& &  
f(x)=\sum_{n\geq 0} a_k(x-1)^{k} \\ 
\hline
Ordre   &   DL_{n}(0)   &   DL_{5}(0)   &  & \\ 
\hline
$\dfrac{1}{1-x}$   &  
\frac{1}{1-x}\eqx \sum_{k=0}^{n} {x^k} +o\bigl(x^{n}\bigr) &  
\frac{1}{1-x}\eqx 1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5+o\bigl(x^{5}\bigr) &  & 
\mathrm{R}=1,\ \forall x\in \mathopen]-1;1[ \quad 
\frac{1}{1-x}=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} {x^n} \\   
\hline
$\dfrac{1}{1+x}$   &  
\frac{1}{1+x}\eqx \sum_{k=0}^{n} (-1)^{k}{x^k} +o\bigl(x^{n}\bigr) &  
\frac{1}{1+x}\eqx  1-x+x^2-x^3+x^4-x^5+o\bigl(x^{5}\bigr) &  & 
\mathrm{R}=1,\ \forall x\in \mathopen]-1;1[\quad 
\frac{1}{1+x}=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} (-1)^{n}{x^n} \\   
\hline
$-\ln(1-x)$   &   
-\ln(1-x) \eqx \sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{x^{k+1}}{k+1} +o\bigl(x^{n}\bigr)  
&  
-\ln(1-x)\eqx  x+{\frac {x^{2}}{2}}+{\frac {x^{3}}{3}}+{\frac {x^{4}}{4}}+{\frac {x^{5}}{5}}+o\bigl(x^{5}\bigr) & & 
\mathrm{R}=1,\ \forall x\in [-1;1[\quad 
-\ln(1-x)=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} \frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1} \\   
\hline
$\ln(1+x)$   &   
\ln(1+x)\eqx \sum_{k=0}^{n} (-1)^{k}\frac{x^{k+1}}{k+1} +o\bigl(x^{n}\bigr)   &  
\ln(1+x)\eqx  x-{\frac {x^{2}}{2}}+{\frac {x^{3}}{3}}-{\frac {x^{4}}{4}}+{\frac {x^{5}}{5}}+o\bigl(x^{5}\bigr)  &  & 
\mathrm{R}=1,\ \forall x\in \mathopen]-1;1]\quad 
\ln(1+x)=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}(-1)^{n}\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}\\   
\hline
& \multicolumn{4}{c|}{On en déduit la somme de la série harmonique alternée $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n}=\ln(2)$} \\  
\hline
$\exp(x)$   & 
\mathrm{e}^{x}\eqx \sum _{k=0}^{n }{\frac {x^{k}}{k!}}+o\bigl(x^{n}\bigr)  &
\mathrm{e}^{x}\eqx  1+{\frac {x}{1!}}+{\frac {x^{2}}{2!}}+{\frac {x^{3}}{3!}}+{\frac {x^{4}}{4!}}+{\frac {x^{5}}{5!}}+o\bigl(x^{5}\bigr) &  & 
\mathrm{R}=+\infty,\ \forall x\in \mathbb{R}\quad 
\mathrm{e}^{x}=\sum _{n=0}^{+\infty }{\frac {x^{n}}{n!}} \\   
\hline
$\ch x$   & 
\ch x\eqx \sum _{k=0}^{n }{\frac {x^{2k}}{(2k)!}}+o\bigl(x^{2n}\bigr) & 
\ch x\eqx  1+{\frac {x^{2}}{2!}}+{\frac {x^{4}}{4!}}+o\bigl(x^{5}\bigr) &  & 
\mathrm{R}=+\infty,\ \forall x\in \mathbb{R},\quad 
\ch x=\sum _{n=0}^{+{\infty }}{\frac {x^{2n}}{(2n)!}} \\   
\hline
$\sh x$   & 
\sh x\eqx \sum _{k=0}^{n}\frac {x^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!} +o\bigl(x^{2n+1}\bigr) &
\sh x\eqx  x+{\frac {x^{3}}{3!}}+{\frac {x^{5}}{5!}}+o\bigl(x^{5}\bigr) &  &
\mathrm{R}=+\infty,\ \forall x\in \mathbb{R},\quad 
\sh x=\sum _{n=0}^{+{\infty }}{\frac {x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}} \\   
\hline
$\cos x$ & 
\cos x\eqx \sum _{k=0}^{n }{(-1)^k\frac {x^{2k}}{(2k)!}}+o\bigl(x^{2n}\bigr)  & 
\cos x\eqx 1-{\frac {x^{2}}{2!}}+{\frac {x^{4}}{4!}}+o\bigl(x^{5}\bigr) &
\begin{aligned}[c] 
   \cos x-1 &\underset{\scriptscriptstyle x\to0}{\sim} -{\frac {x^{2}}{2!}}\\
   1-\cos x &\underset{\scriptscriptstyle x\to0}{\sim} {\frac {x^{2}}{2!}} 
\end{aligned} &
\mathrm{R}=+\infty,\ \forall x\in \mathbb{R},\quad 
\cos x=\sum _{n=0}^{+{\infty }}{(-1)^n\frac {x^{2n}}{(2n)!}} \\   
\hline
$\sin x$   & 
\sin x\eqx  \sum _{k=0}^{n }{(-1)^k\frac {x^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!}}+o\bigl(x^{2n+1}\bigr)   & 
\sin x\eqx   x-{\frac {x^{3}}{3!}}+{\frac {x^{5}}{5!}}+o\bigl(x^{5}\bigr) &  &
\mathrm{R}=+\infty,\ \forall x\in \mathbb{R},\quad 
\sin x=\sum _{n=0}^{+{\infty }}{(-1)^n\frac {x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}} \\   
\hline
$\arctan x$   & \arctan x\eqx  \sum _{k=0}^{n }{(-1)^k\frac {x^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)}}+o\bigl(x^{2n+1}\bigr) & 
\arctan x\eqx   x-{\frac {x^{3}}{3}}+{\frac {x^{5}}{5}}+o\bigl(x^{5}\bigr) &  & 
\mathrm{R}=1,\  \forall x\in [-1;1](x\not =\pm i),\quad 
\arctan x=\sum _{n=0}^{+{\infty }}{(-1)^n\frac {x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)}} \\   
\hline
$\arctanh x$   &
\arctanh x\eqx \sum _{k=0}^{n }{\frac {x^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)}}+o\bigl(x^{2n+1}\bigr)  &  
\arctanh x\eqx  x+{\frac {x^{3}}{3}}+{\frac {x^{5}}{5}}+o\bigl(x^{5}\bigr) &  & 
\mathrm{R}=1,\  \forall x\in \mathopen]-1;1[,\quad 
\arctanh x=\sum _{n=0}^{+{\infty }}{\frac {x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)}} \\   
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{sidewaystable}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\end{document}
```

Comment: this is totally  awesome

Comment: note that when i add others colums to my table won't fit the whole page what can i do in this case

Comment: @Educ - With this solution, the table's main (relative) font size is `\scriptsize`, which represents a 30% linear reduction from `\normalsize`. If you add more columns, the font size will have to be reduced further. With one or two more additional columns, I would suspect that the material will no longer be readable unless you also provide a magnifying glass...

Comment: yes you're right

Answer (score 2):

Follow this table coding in your document: I just used `sidewaystable` with the package `rotating`

```
\begin{sidewaystable}
  %\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
    \begin{adjustbox}{width=1\textwidth}
\makegapedcells
    \begin{tabular}{ | c | *{5}{>{$\displaystyle}c<{$}|}}
    \hline
    Mohcine    &   \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Développement limité en 0 de fonctions usuelles }    & \text{ Equivalents} & \text{ Développements en série entière usuels} \\ \hline
            Théorème         &   \multicolumn{2}{c|}{$\displaystyle
            f(x)\underset{{x\to a}}{=}\sum_{k=0}^{n}a_k(x-1)^{k}+o((x-a)^{n})$}
                                                &  &   f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} a_n(x)^{n}     \\
    \hline
Formulaire        &   \multicolumn{2}{c|}{$\displaystyle
            f(x)\underset{{x\to a}}{=}\sum_{k=0}^{n}a_k(x-1)^{k}+o((x-a)^{n})$}
                                               & &  f(x)=\sum_{n\geq 0} a_k(x-1)^{k}    \\
    \hline
Ordre   &   DL_{n}(0)   &   DL_{5}(0)           &  &                                      \\
    \hline
        $\dfrac{1}{1-x}$   &  \dfrac{1}{1-x}\underset{{x\to 0}}{=}\sum_{k=0}^{n} {x^k} +o(x^{n})
                        &  \dfrac{1}{1-x}\underset{{x\to 0}}{=}1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5+o(x^{5}) &  & \rm{R}=1,\ \forall x\in ]-1;1[\quad \dfrac{1}{1-x}=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} {x^n}       \\
    \hline
            $\dfrac{1}{1+x}$   &  \dfrac{1}{1+x}\underset{{x\to 0}}{=}\sum_{k=0}^{n} (-1)^{k}{x^k} +o(x^{n})
                        &  \dfrac{1}{1+x}\underset{{x\to 0}}{=} 1-x+x^2-x^3+x^4-x^5+o(x^{5}) &  & \rm{R}=1,\ \forall x\in ]-1;1[\quad \dfrac{1}{1+x}=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} (-1)^{n}{x^n}       \\
    \hline
                $-\ln(1-x)$   &   -\ln(1-x)\underset{{x\to 0}}{=}\sum_{k=0}^{n} \dfrac{x^{k+1}}{k+1} +o(x^{n})
                        &  -\ln(1-x)\underset{{x\to 0}}{=} x+{\frac {x^{2}}{2}}+{\frac {x^{3}}{3}}+{\frac {x^{4}}{4}}+{\frac {x^{5}}{5}}+o(x^{5})  &  & \rm{R}=1,\ \forall x\in [-1;1[\quad -\ln(1-x)=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} \dfrac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}      \\
    \hline
            $\ln(1+x)$   &   \ln(1+x)\underset{{x\to 0}}{=}\sum_{k=0}^{n} (-1)^{k}\dfrac{x^{k+1}}{k+1} +o(x^{n})
                        &  \ln(1+x)\underset{{x\to 0}}{=} x-{\frac {x^{2}}{2}}+{\frac {x^{3}}{3}}-{\frac {x^{4}}{4}}+{\frac {x^{5}}{5}}+o(x^{5})  &  &
                                                {\displaystyle\rm{R}=1,\ \forall x\in ]-1;1]\quad \ln(1+x)=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} (-1)^{n}\dfrac{x^{n+1}}{n+1} }     \\
    \hline
                & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{ On en déduit la somme de la série harmonique alternée  $\displaystyle\quad  \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \dfrac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n}=\ln(2)$ } \\
        \hline

$\exp(x)$   &   {\displaystyle {\rm {e}}^{x}\underset{{x\to 0}}{=}\sum _{k=0}^{n }{\frac {x^{k}}{k!}}+o(x^{n}) }
                        &  {\displaystyle {\rm {e}}^{x}\underset{{x\to 0}}{=} 1+{\frac {x}{1!}}+{\frac {x^{2}}{2!}}+{\frac {x^{3}}{3!}}+{\frac {x^{4}}{4!}}+{\frac {x^{5}}{5!}}+o(x^{5})} &  & {\displaystyle \rm{R}=+\infty,\ \forall x\in \mathbb{R}\quad {\rm {e}}^{x}=\sum _{n=0}^{+\infty }{\frac {x^{n}}{n!}}}        \\
    \hline
        $\operatorname {ch} \,x$   &   {\displaystyle \operatorname {ch} \,x\underset{{x\to 0}}{=}\sum _{k=0}^{n }{\frac {x^{2k}}{(2\,k)!}}+o(x^{2n}) }
                        &  {\displaystyle \operatorname {ch} \,x\underset{{x\to 0}}{=} 1+{\frac {x^{2}}{2!}}+{\frac {x^{4}}{4!}}+o(x^{5})} &  & {\displaystyle \rm{R}=+\infty,\ \forall x\in \mathbb{R}\quad  ,\,\operatorname{ch} \,x=\sum _{n=0}^{+{\infty }}{\frac {x^{2n}}{(2\,n)!}}}        \\
    \hline
            $\operatorname {sh} \,x$   &   {\displaystyle \operatorname {sh} \,x\underset{{x\to 0}}{=}\sum _{k=0}^{n }{\frac {x^{2k+1}}{(2\,k+1)!}}+o(x^{2n+1}) }
                        &  {\displaystyle \operatorname {sh} \,x\underset{{x\to 0}}{=} x+{\frac {x^{3}}{3!}}+{\frac {x^{5}}{5!}}+o(x^{5})} &  & {\displaystyle \rm{R}=+\infty,\ \forall x\in \mathbb{R}\quad  ,\,\operatorname{sh} \,x=\sum _{n=0}^{+{\infty }}{\frac {x^{2n+1}}{(2\,n+1)!}}}        \\
    \hline
                        $\cos \,x$   &   {\displaystyle \cos \,x\underset{{x\to 0}}{=} \sum _{k=0}^{n }{(-1)^k\frac {x^{2k}}{(2\,k)!}}+o(x^{2n}) }
                        &  {\displaystyle \cos \,x\underset{{x\to 0}}{=}  1-{\frac {x^{2}}{2!}}+{\frac {x^{4}}{4!}}+o(x^{5})}
                                                & {\displaystyle\begin{aligned}[c] \cos \,x-1 &\underset{{x\to 0}}{\sim} -{\frac {x^{2}}{2!}}\\
1-\cos \,x &\underset{{x\to 0}}{\sim} {\frac {x^{2}}{2!}} \end{aligned}}   &
                                                {\displaystyle \rm{R}=+\infty,\ \forall x\in \mathbb{R}\quad  ,\,\cos \,x=\sum _{n=0}^{+{\infty }}{(-1)^n\frac {x^{2n}}{(2\,n)!}}}        \\
    \hline
            $\sin \,x$   &   {\displaystyle \sin \,x\underset{{x\to 0}}{=} \sum _{k=0}^{n }{(-1)^k\frac {x^{2k+1}}{(2\,k+1)!}}+o(x^{2n+1}) }
                        &  {\displaystyle \sin \,x\underset{{x\to 0}}{=}  x-{\frac {x^{3}}{3!}}+{\frac {x^{5}}{5!}}+o(x^{5})} &  & {\displaystyle \rm{R}=+\infty,\ \forall x\in \mathbb{R}\quad  ,\,\sin \,x=\sum _{n=0}^{+{\infty }}{(-1)^n\frac {x^{2n+1}}{(2\,n+1)!}}}        \\
    \hline
        $\arctan \,x$   &   {\displaystyle \arctan \,x\underset{{x\to 0}}{=} \sum _{k=0}^{n }{(-1)^k\frac {x^{2k+1}}{(2\,k+1)}}+o(x^{2n+1}) }
                        &  {\displaystyle \arctan  \,x\underset{{x\to 0}}{=}  x-{\frac {x^{3}}{3}}+{\frac {x^{5}}{5}}+o(x^{5})} &  & {\displaystyle \rm{R}=1,\  \forall x\in [-1;1](x\not =\pm i)\quad  ,\,\arctan  \,x=\sum _{n=0}^{+{\infty }}{(-1)^n\frac {x^{2n+1}}{(2\,n+1)}}}        \\
    \hline
            $\operatorname {arctanh} \,x$   &   {\displaystyle \operatorname {arctanh} \,x\underset{{x\to 0}}{=}\sum _{k=0}^{n }{\frac {x^{2k+1}}{(2\,k+1)}}+o(x^{2n+1}) }
                        &  {\displaystyle \operatorname {arctanh} \,x\underset{{x\to 0}}{=} x+{\frac {x^{3}}{3}}+{\frac {x^{5}}{5}}+o(x^{5})} &  & {\displaystyle \rm{R}=1,\  \forall x\in ]-1;1[\quad  ,\,\operatorname {arctanh} \,x=\sum _{n=0}^{+{\infty }}{\frac {x^{2n+1}}{(2\,n+1)}}}        \\
    \hline
                    \end{tabular}
    %}
    \end{adjustbox}
 \end{sidewaystable}
```

use the coding `\usepackage{rotating}` in preamble part.

Answer (score 2):

use `\resizebox{.96\linewidth}{!}{...}` and remove the `table` environment

the .96 value ensure that the table will not move to the next page.

[image]

`\linewidth` shoud be used in landscape mode instead of `\textwidth`

Comment: Wouldn't a tabularx-environment be the more clever way to solve this problem?

Comment: not sure, you would need to manually adjust the width of the multicols, that seems to be much more work than using resizebox

Comment: suppose, you set up a very wide tabular.  Than `\resizebox` will obviously ensure, that the table will fit onto the page, regardless its natural width.  The only drawback is, that the content will be decreases in size so much, that it is unreadable.  What have you gained?

Comment: well, this is a different, general problem. I was referring only to the table posted by the OP, which is readable when resized.